# How to load Javascript file in a Service Worker dynamically?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I can't use any solutions that involve creating a `<script>` tag dynamically because `document` does not exist in a ServiceWorker context.

In this case I want to load analytics toolkit so I can track when SW-triggered Notifications are interacted with by the user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That sounds like the intended use case of the [`importScripts()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts).

The imported script shares the global scope with your service worker, so modifying `self` via, e.g., `self.addEventListener()` or `self.someIdentifier = 'blah'` will have the same effect as it would from within the main service worker script.

Comment: Yes, that definitely looks like it does the trick. Unfortunately since asking the question I realized that the analytics library I want to load also depends on `document` so I'll have to go another route.

Comment: Although importScripts is a good method it doesn't really work for truly dynamic loading of JS files as it can't be located in functions. So, to dynamically call JS you have to `fetch` the JS and then do an `eval`. Unless there is a better way than I know about.