# Failed to register a ServiceWorker, script evaluation failed

Tags: javascript

I have created a service worker and I need to add an external JS library to it. According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts), I can use `importScripts(URL)` to do that. The first line of my `sw.js` is:

```
self.importScripts('https://cdn.scaledrone.com/scaledrone.min.js');
```

But when I register the Service worker I get this error with a reference to that line. (If I remove that line the error message is gone)

```
Uncaught null

TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://example.com/sw/') 
with script ('http://example.com/sw/sw.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems to work for most people. ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932176/can-i-call-a-method-from-an-external-js-file-in-a-serviceworker), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55628146/how-to-import-a-script-in-service-worker-when-using-webpack#answer-60021256), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887600/importscripts-in-service-worker) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251929/how-to-load-javascript-file-in-a-service-worker-dynamically))

Comment: any solution so found please im stuck in it

Comment: @Ahmad, it has been a while, but if I remember correctly there where two different versions of the script. The one I have above was for referencing inside an HTML document. Buried in the docs I found one that could be used within a script. Are you using Scale Drone?

Comment: No i am using GCM . thanks my issue resolved .